# How do you override Magento\Catalog\Block\Category\View?

Tags: magento2, overrides, catalog, preference

I want to override the protected function `_prepareLayout()`

So i have used preference

```
<preference for="Magento\Catalog\Block\Category\View" type="Module\Name\Block\Category\View"/>
```

```
class View extends \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View
{
    protected $_urlInterface;


    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Resolver $layerResolver,
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
        \Magento\Catalog\Helper\Category $categoryHelper,
        \Magento\Framework\UrlInterface $urlInterface,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->_urlInterface = $urlInterface;
        parent::__construct($context, $layerResolver, $registry, $categoryHelper, $data);
    }

    /**
     * @return $this
     */
    protected function _prepareLayout()
    {
        die(var_dump($this));
        parent::_prepareLayout();

        $this->getLayout()->createBlock(\Magento\Catalog\Block\Breadcrumbs::class);


        $category = $this->getCurrentCategory();
        if ($category) {
            $title = $category->getMetaTitle();
            if ($title) {
                $this->pageConfig->getTitle()->set($title);
            }
            $description = $category->getMetaDescription();
            if ($description) {
                $this->pageConfig->setDescription($description);
            }
            $keywords = $category->getMetaKeywords();
            if ($keywords) {
                $this->pageConfig->setKeywords($keywords);
            }
            if ($this->_categoryHelper->canUseCanonicalTag()) {
                $this->pageConfig->addRemotePageAsset(
                    // $category->getUrl(),
                    $this->_urlInterface->getCurrentUrl(),
                    'canonical',
                    ['attributes' => ['rel' => 'canonical']]
                );
            }

            $pageMainTitle = $this->getLayout()->getBlock('page.main.title');
            if ($pageMainTitle) {
                $pageMainTitle->setPageTitle($this->getCurrentCategory()->getName());
            }
        }

        return $this;
    }
```

but i get error 500

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View::__construct() must be an instance of Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\Context, instance of Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context

Comment: What you want to achieve by override that file?

Comment: insted of calling this => $category->getUrl(),
I want it to call ->$this->_urlInterface->getCurrentUrl(),
that's all 
Adding new DI to consturct and call $this->_urlInterface->getCurrentUrl(),

Comment: which magetn version, you are  using?

Comment: magento v:2.2.10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to replace your construct function with this

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Block\Category;

use Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\Category;

class View extends \Magento\Catalog\Block\Category\View
{
    protected $_urlInterface;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Resolver $layerResolver,
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
        \Magento\Catalog\Helper\Category $categoryHelper,
        \Magento\Framework\UrlInterface $urlInterface,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->_urlInterface = $urlInterface;
        $this->_categoryHelper = $categoryHelper;
        $this->_catalogLayer = $layerResolver->get();
        $this->_coreRegistry = $registry;
        parent::__construct($context, $layerResolver, $registry, $categoryHelper, $data);
    }

    protected function _prepareLayout()
    {
        echo "123";die;
        parent::_prepareLayout();

        $this->getLayout()->createBlock(\Magento\Catalog\Block\Breadcrumbs::class);

        $category = $this->getCurrentCategory();
        if ($category) {
            $title = $category->getMetaTitle();
            if ($title) {
                $this->pageConfig->getTitle()->set($title);
            }
            $description = $category->getMetaDescription();
            if ($description) {
                $this->pageConfig->setDescription($description);
            }
            $keywords = $category->getMetaKeywords();
            if ($keywords) {
                $this->pageConfig->setKeywords($keywords);
            }
            if ($this->_categoryHelper->canUseCanonicalTag()) {
                $this->pageConfig->addRemotePageAsset(
                    $category->getUrl(),
                    'canonical',
                    ['attributes' => ['rel' => 'canonical']]
                );
            }

            $pageMainTitle = $this->getLayout()->getBlock('page.main.title');
            if ($pageMainTitle) {
                $pageMainTitle->setPageTitle($this->getCurrentCategory()->getName());
            }
        }

        return $this;
    }
}
```

Then run below commands once

```
rm -rf generated/* var/view_preprocessed/*
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento cache:clean
php bin/magento cache:flush
```

Hope this will help you!

Comment: Still getting the same error PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View::__construct() must be an instance of Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\Context, instance of Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context

Comment: Did you run all commands ? after changing construct ?

Comment: Yes i did
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento cache:clean
php bin/magento cache:flush
and i did 
rm -rf var/di/* var/generation/* var/cache/* var/log/* var/page_cache/* var/session/* var/view_preprocessed/* pub/static/*

Comment: Which Magento version do you have ?

Comment: magento v:2.2.10

Comment: i have updated @Kishan

Comment: I've updated my answer. Please use only that code and remove other functions for now and run setup upgrade once and then check

Comment: remove protected function _prepareLayout()

Comment: this echo worked :) 
what was the error?

Comment: You didn't passed arguments in parent construct **parent::__construct($context, $layerResolver, $registry, $categoryHelper, $data);**

Comment: but that wasn't in the parent class though or am i wrong?

Comment: If you'll check parent file's construct function then they are passing 5 arguments in params and you just passed $contect and $data. So if you'll pass all other then it will work. And whenever you will add anything in construct at that time you need to run setup upgrade or di compile once. :)

Comment: Approve answer. If it helps. Thanks :)

Comment: I have done and one more question i am getting double canonical do you know why that causing it 
I have changed                     $category->getUrl(), to                     $this->_urlInterface->getCurrentUrl(),